# Make 1 Thread wait for an array of Threads to complete

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

I have an array of threads called workers. There is another separate thread called status.

Both threads access a shared LinkedBlockingQueue. Workers(thread array) uses poll() to pull work and status reports the size of the queue every 30 seconds.

My problem in running this is I get the following printed from the status class:

> UPLOADING...
>
> PREVIEWING...

But PREVIEWING should appear before, and only before, UPLOADING.
So, I think my status object is not waiting for the first batch of workers to complete?

I want this:

> DOWNLOADING....
>
> PREVIEWING....
>
> UPLOADING...

but instead things are a bit out of sync.

```
// start up the Status Object class.
        int downloadSize = filesToDownload.size();
        Thread statusThread = new Thread(new Status(filesToDownload, currentYear, downloadSize, "DOWNLOADING..."));
        statusThread.start();

        /**
         * download the files
         */

        Thread[] workers = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
        for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; x++) {
            workers[x] = new Thread(new S3ObjectDownloader(filesToDownload, currentYear));
            workers[x].start();
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; x++) {
            try {
                workers[x].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * create previews
         */
        int previewSize = filesToPreview.size();
        statusThread = new Thread(new Status(filesToPreview, currentYear, previewSize, "PREVIEWING..."));
        statusThread.start();

        workers = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
        for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; x++) {
            workers[x] = new Thread(new Worker(filesToPreview, currentYear));
            workers[x].start();
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; x++) {
            try {
                workers[x].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        /**
         * upload previews to S3.
         */
        // we need the TransferManager for the uploads.
        TransferManager txManager = new TransferManager(new ClasspathPropertiesFileCredentialsProvider());
        statusThread = new Thread(new Status(filesToUpload, currentYear, filesToUpload.size(), "UPLOADING..."));
        statusThread.start();

        workers = new Thread[NUMBER_OF_THREADS];
        for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; x++) {
            workers[x] = new Thread(new S3ObjectUploader(filesToUpload, currentYear, txManager));
            workers[x].start();
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; x++) {
            try {
                workers[x].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { 
                // TODO Auto-generated catch
                // block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // shutdown transfer manager
        txManager.shutdownNow();
```

Here is Status.java

```
public class Status implements Runnable {

    private String conferenceYear;
    private Queue<String>queue;
    private int queueSize;
    private String jobeName;

    public Status(Queue<String> queue, String conferenceYear, int queueSize, String jobName){
        this.conferenceYear = conferenceYear;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.queueSize = queueSize;
        this.jobeName = jobName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            try {
                float completion = (queue.size() * 1.0f) / this.queueSize;
                System.out.println(this.jobeName+" : "+this.conferenceYear+ " remaining..."+MessageFormat.format("{0,number,#.##%}",completion));
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java has CountDownlatches to support such scenarios.

Take a look at [CountDownLatch](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) class.

The link also contains a sample implementation which is very easy to understand. You can create latches to signal start and wait for end for each of your task.